# Can't get git remote add origin to add repo

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I haven't used my bitbucket account for some time. 
I have local project on branch master, everything committed, which I want to move there
When I enter

```
git remote add origin git@bb:my_user/my_repo.git
```

to move my repo to bitbucket. I get nothing.
No errors, no messages and my repo doesn't appear on bitbucket under my repositories.

If I try then

```
git push -u origin --all
```

I get

```
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The funniest thing is: if I try first command (add origin) again, I get

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

In the same time I can successfully push/pull/clone my repos that are already on bitbucket.
And

```
ssh -T git@bb
```

gives me correct response:

```
logged in as my_user.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

Could you help me to pinpoint this issue?

Comment: You have to create repo on bitbucket first. From the website.

Comment: @mszymborski is correct.  Note that running "git remote add ..." doesn't do anything other than register a mapping between the name you provide (e.g, "origin") and the corresponding URL.  It doesn't attempt to transfer anything between your local repository and the remote.

Comment: And actually it turns out that there's a REST api you can use to create a new repo, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788485/create-new-repo-on-bitbucket-from-git-bash-terminal

Comment: That sound reasonable. One good holiday not using git and I completely forgot it. So now they have REST I see. That means I can write the command sequence and not forget it anymore. Thank you guys.